# NameError when overriding __init__ of ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform

I hope you can help me to figure out what's wrong with this code:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import Persona

class PersonaForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        exclude = ('cuenta',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cuenta = kwargs.pop('cuenta')
        super(PersonaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['organizacion'].queryset = Organizacion.objects.filter(cuenta=cuenta)
```

I get the following error: `name 'PersonaForm' is not defined`

This is the whole traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/tomate/tomate/urls.py" in <module>
  18.     url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  25.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/tomate/dashboard/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from dashboard import views
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/tomate/dashboard/views.py" in <module>
  7. from forms import PersonaForm
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/tomate/dashboard/forms.py" in <module>
  4. class PersonaForm(ModelForm):
File "/Applications/djangostack-1.4.5-0/apps/django/django_projects/tomate/dashboard/forms.py" in PersonaForm
  12.         super(PersonaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: NameError at /
Exception Value: name 'PersonaForm' is not defined
```

I have looked for an answer around but has not found anything yet...
Thanks!

Comment: The code seems fine, can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: Hi mariodev! Just added the traceback. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: Looks fine. It could well be stale pyc files. Just delete the pyc file, and restart the server and try again.

Comment: karthikr: Unfortunately, it didn't work.Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Where is ```PersonaForm```? Is it in that same file?

Comment: `PersonaForm` is in `forms.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you have an indentation error there. Looking at the traceback, the line with `super` is being executed when forms.py is being imported, which shouldn't usually happen if it's inside the `__init__` method. So I would guess you have that line at the same level as the method definitions, and it is being executed when the form class is defined. Check you aren't mixing tabs and spaces anywhere, for example.